# Authentication not sticking on my custom Security Token Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif

I've created a custom STS using asp.net 4.5.  It works, I am able to authenticate and receive the claims.  However if I refresh my page or navigate to a different page after the authentication, my 'audience' site keeps going back to my issuer site for each request.

After I have authenticated, even tough it goes back to the issuer, it take me right back to my 'audience' site confirming that I am authenticated.  However, the claims are no longer passed along.

Is there a setting that I am missing which allows the audience site to save the authentication cookie and claims?

My audience site is an MVC site.

Just an observation I've notice: When I run the audience site on my local IIS, I do not have this issue. It works just fine.  Only when I deploy it to Azure Websites is when I have this issue.

This is the service settings:

```
<federationConfiguration>
  <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
  <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://auth.mydomain.com/" realm="https://apps.mydomain.com/" requireHttps="true" persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true" />
</federationConfiguration>
```

Comment: Sounds like a cookie issue. Make sure your relying party issues a cookie and keeps it between requests. Edit your question to provide more details on that if you want more help.

Comment: @WiktorZychla is this a configuration on the system.identitymodel?  I have not specified anything about cookie on the relying party config.

Comment: Definitely at the relying party side.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I've added <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" persistentSessionLifetime="60.0:0:0"  /> to <federationConfiguration>, however the authentication cookie is not been stored in the relaying party.  Would you have a link with some instructions on how to set it up?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thank you for the help.  I found the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by re-running the Identity and Access tool.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e

They added the following values that made it work.
The values were added to section securityTokenHandlers under system.identityModel > identityConfiguration. In case anyone has the same problem.

```
<add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```